# Find all users(reply_channels) added in Group (Django channels)

Tags: python, django, chat, django-channels

I am using Django channels Group to build a chat system and want to fetch all the users in chat room.

Group provide these methods :

- `Group("group_name").add(message.reply_channel)`
- `Group("group_name").discard(message.reply_channel)`
- `Group("group_name").send({"text": "My group message",})`

But there is nothing like that I can find all users(reply_channel) in Group.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Django Channels have purposely avoided the ability to determine all the users, mainly due to scalability concerns. Read [this](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/174)

However, there is [this](https://github.com/ml-learning/django-channels-presence) package called Django Channels Presence, which allows you to determine the users currently in a room, and they use a different mechanism so that it scales differently compared to Django Channels.