# Get list of connected users in a room with django channels

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-channels

How can we get the list of connected users to a room within channel with Django Channels? I know this question has been asked many times, but honestly, I've scoured all over the internet and I'm very surprised there isn't a conventional way of doing so. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48591125/3480297) answer, Django Channels have avoided this scenario, however, there is another package, [Django Presence](https://django-channels-presence.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html), that can cater for it.

So far, I've got a very simple app where a websocket broadcasts data that is sent from each client, so that each connected client in a room receives that data. I've also got a simple authentication so that only authenticated users can connect. This is what I have:

**routing.py**

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "websocket": TokenAuthMiddleware(
            URLRouter([
                re_path(r'ws/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.MyConsumer.as_asgi()),
            ])
        )
    }
)
```

**middleware.py**

```
class TokenAuthMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, inner):
        super().__init__(inner)

    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        # Get the token
        token = parse_qs(scope["query_string"].decode("utf8"))["token"][0]

        #custom code to validate token
        if token_is_valid:
            # assign scope['user'] = user
        else:
            scope['user'] = AnonymousUser()

        return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
```

**consumer.py**

```
    def connect(self):
        user = self.scope["user"]

        if user.is_anonymous:
            self.close()
        else:
            self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
            async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add) (
                self.room_name,
                self.channel_name
            )

            self.accept() # WHAT CAN I DO HERE TO RETURN THE LIST OF CONNECTED USERS IN THIS SAME ROOM NAME?

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard) (
            self.room_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
```

with regards to my comment in the `consumers`, two ideas come to my mind (the first probably better than the second):

1. Make use of the in memory channel layer to track which users connect/disconnect. In doing so, I'd like for the list of users to be replied back to the established connection (i.e. the client) on connect. How can this be done?
2. Alternatively, I've seen examples where we can track a user's activity (i.e. online/away/offline etc) using the database. This for me isn't a totally optimal solution since I don't want to be querying the database for that sort of activity.

If there is a better solution, I'm all ears, but essentially, how can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

If you use RedisChannelLayer, extend them with next method:

```
class ExtendedRedisChannelLayer(RedisChannelLayer):

    async def get_group_channels(self, group):
        assert self.valid_group_name(group), "Group name not valid"
        key = self._group_key(group)
        connection = self.connection(self.consistent_hash(group))
        # Discard old channels based on group_expiry
        await connection.zremrangebyscore(
            key, min=0, max=int(time.time()) - self.group_expiry
        )

        return [x.decode("utf8") for x in await connection.zrange(key, 0, -1)]
```

define in settings:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "your_path.ExtendedRedisChannelLayer",
        ...
    }
}
```

use inside the consumer:

```
group_channels = await self.channel_layer.get_group_channels('group_name')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a model `chat` which will represent this `room`

```
class Chat(models.Model):

    #collect in charfield `pk` of all users online 
    users_online = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
```

then when any user connects to the websocket, add him to `Chat's` field `users_online`:

```
def connect(self):
    user = self.scope["user"]

    if user.is_anonymous:
        self.close()
    else:
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add) (
            self.room_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept() 
        
        #after user successfully conected
        chat_object = Chat.objects.get(get_chat_object = here)
        # first option append it with semicolon, so later you could split list
        chat_object.users_online.append(str(user.pk)+";")
        self.custom_user_list = []
```

When user disconnets from your websocket, `remove` users `pk` from the `users_online` field

Comment: Thank you. There must be a better way to track the users rather than creating a model and querying the database each time a user connects/disconnects though right? Can we use the in memory layer for this?

Comment: @Adam, you can see all your opened rooms with this command `redis-cli KEYS '*'` in console, but it doesn't show people inside it. I believe there may be a way how to look people in memory layer, if it is i think it would be on this `self.channel_layer` variable, it is actually redis server

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't tested it in production, I was able to handle this by adding a `defaultdict` as a class attribute to my consumer, and keeping track of the relevant connection information in-memory. For my use case, I only was concerned with the count of users:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

class MyConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
        room_connection_counts = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

        async def connect(self):
            self.user = self.scope['user']
            self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
            self.room_group_name = f'group_{self.room_name}'

            await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                self.room_group_name,
                self.channel_name,
            )

            await self.accept()

            self.room_connection_counts[self.room_name] += 1

            print(
                "Connection Count:",
                self.room_connection_counts[self.room_name]
            )

        async def disconnect(self):
            await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
                self.room_group_name,
                self.channel_name,
            )
            self.room_connection_counts[self.room_name] -= 1
            print(
                "Connection Count:",
                self.room_connection_counts[self.room_name]
            )
```

In your case, you want to keep track of a list of connected users. To do that, you would modify the `room_connection_counts` `defaultdict` to return a `list` or `set` of users by default. For example, in the class body, you would use:

```
room_connected_users = defaultdict(set)
```

And in the connect method, you would use:

```
self.room_connected_users[self.room_name].add(self.user)
```

And in the disconnect:

```
self.room_connected_users[self.room_name].remove(self.user)
```

For the second part of your question, you want to send the list of connected users back to the channel group. You can do that by adding the following in your connect method:

```
async def connect(self):
    ...
    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        self.room_group_name,
        {
            'type': 'user_connect',
            'message': list(self.room_connected_users[self.room_name])
        }
    )
```

And define a `user_connect` method in your consumer, to be called by the group_send method:

```
async def user_connect(self, event):
    message = event['message']

    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'type': 'player_connect',
        'message': message
    }))
```

You would follow the same pattern to send a message on disconnect as well.

Of course, you have to be careful not to overload your memory, so you might wish to put limits on how many users can be stored for a single room before passing it along to the db.

I hope this helps! I'm curious to hear the benefits/drawbacks others see in this approach vs. making calls out to the db.